# Lowering power output from amp to speakers

Tags: amplifier, audio, speakers

I have a pair of 8 ohm speakers that are rated for max 60w and a receiver that outputs 160w and is rated for 8 ohms. I wired everything up and, as expected, even at minimum volume it was too loud. I know almost nothing about electrical engineering, so bear with me... Can I use something like this to decrease the power flowing to the speakers? Would it just go in-line with the speaker wire going to each speaker? Is there a better approach to make these two components work together? Thanks! [image]
edit: removed the misleading note on distortion. main issue is amp outputting too much volume

edit: Thanks everyone for the help! To clear up some of the questions.. I am running a turntable with a Pluto 2 preamp to a Technics SA-ex110 then to a set of Yamaha NS-A528. After everyone's input I thought to try running the turntable without the preamp and it works great. Expected volume sensitivity and no distortion.

Comment: Instead of attenuating *output*, try attenuating *input* with a voltage divider: perhaps a variable resistor of 10k to 20k. Amplifier output should connect directly to the speaker(s).

Comment: Would something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Calrad-Electronics-Stereo-Variable-Attenuator/dp/B01LBB9YTY/ref=sr_1_5?crid=6C9DGKD2V3X7&keywords=rca+attenuator&qid=1687190693&sprefix=rca+attenuator%2Caps%2C119&sr=8-5) help?

Comment: Your 160W amp is not pushing 160W out into the speakers all the time. It only does that (or at least tries to) when you turn the volume all the way up to 11. At lower volume control settings, the amp will be sending less power to the speakers. So if you're still getting distortion at low volume settings then adding resistors is not going to help you. Perhaps you've already damaged your speakers and that's what's causing your distortion - in which case adding resistors to protect the new speakers you're going to buy might be a reasonable idea ...

Comment: Without input attenuated properly, an amplifier is driven into clipping - hard or soft. With a multiway speaker system, the tweeter is about as likely to get damaged with a 9 W amplifier as with an 160 W one.

Comment: That input attenuator *might* help.... both @greybeard and myself suspect your power amplifier *might* be over-driven, causing distortion. You haven't mentioned where in the signal chain signal level is controlled. Or what device drives the power amplifier: conventional signal chains have at least one volume control that includes zero volume at one end. Your symptoms (too loud at minimum volume) are unusual. That, coupled with "distortion" might mean a different fault that an input attenuator won't address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can. But it won't solve your problem as it is elsewhere.

It is unlikely that the source of distortion at low volume is because you connected 60W speakers to a 160W amplifier, so this is not solved by putting resistors between amplifer output and speaker.

Comment: What I'm really looking for is, would this set up reduce the amount of power flowing to the speakers in a safe way that also wouldn't affect quality too much? Thanks for a quick response btw!

Comment: I said it would reduce power, and I also said the problem is not too much power flowing into speaker, so adding the resistors won't help a bit about bad sound quality. If you have distortion at low volume, the problem is not that too much power goes to a speaker.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of receiver has a minimal volume that is significantly different from silence?

At any rate, speakers rated for 80W tend to output *less* sound volume at equal input power than speakers rated for 160W because they tend to be limited in the amount of air they can move due to smaller woofers, and smaller woofers tend to be less efficient.

So all this does not really sound like you spotted the problem correctly.

To make your idea even worse, speakers have a complex and frequency-varying impedance, and their frequency range is specified in terms of the applied voltage.  If you connect a resistor in series, this means that the speakers will become relatively louder at their higher impedance ranges and relatively quieter at their lower impedance ranges.

The only thing you should connect in series with a given speaker is another speaker of identical kind (very strictly speaking, even placing a second speaker in a different room changes its electrical characteristics, but for practical purposes nobody is bothered by that, and at the typical low efficiencies, the influence of the room on the electric behavior is comparatively small).

Also you have to be aware that the difference between 60 W and 160 W is a meagre 4 dB on the input of the speaker.  That kind of change should easily be in the purview of a volume control.  Just don't turn your amp up all the way.

On the plus side, nothing kills tweeters faster than overdriving a solidstate amp, and it would appear that the amp power is not the problem in your case.  Assuming that the wattage numbers are made in a similar meaning.

By the way: the resistor you list is 0.8 Ohm, not 8 Ohm.  It would not change loudness a whole lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have distortion across all volume ranges, it sounds like you have a gain staging issue somewhere else in your signal chain rather than the output of the amp.  I would check that you aren't overloading your input stage (see any peaking indicators?).  Other things you could check is if you have an oscilloscope, you could put it on the output of the amplifier while it's being driving from a tone generator across several frequencies to make sure the amp is still good (maybe internal failures).

Answer (score -1):

The sensitivity of our hearing is logarithmic.
Then the 0.8 ohms resistor will reduce the 160W to 132W and sound at the same loudness.
16W sounds half as loud as 160W, 160W sounds twice as loud as 16W.